# How do I map non-null elements without an assertion in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to find better way to chain the `filter` and `map` operators in Kotlin. What I want to do is to filter the null items before going to the `map` operator.

I was able to chain them, but the compiler complained about the nullability of my list items.

```
class Person(val age : String?)

fun foo(age :String){
    // require non-null age
}
```

The sample usage was:

```
val list = mutableListOf(Person("3"), Person("2"))

list.filter{ it.age != null }.map{ foo(it.age) }
// The IDE wants me to add !!
```

So why can't Kotlin infer the nullability? The filtered (all non-null) items passed down to map should had been filtered to ensure that they are non-null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace `filter` and `map` with one method [mapNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html):

```kotlin
val list2 = list.mapNotNull { it.age }
```

Comment: thanks for point this out! this is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This case may seem easy for a human, but technically speaking it would be really hard for the compiler to understand that after filtering it is a list of `people` objects, but with different type of the `age` property than original.

If you don't use a whole `people` instance at `map()` stage then I think the easiest would be to do:

```
list
    .mapNotNull { it.age }
    .map(::foo)
```

Or, if your `foo()` can't return nulls:

```
list.mapNotNull { it.age?.let(::foo) }
```

But I think this is less readable. Or you can just use `!!` - it's not that bad if we know what we're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Iterable<T>.filterNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) extension function here which will return a list of the non-nullable type.

In your case, the compiler just isn't advanced enough to smart-cast the filtered list, it would be quite a lot to ask. So if you need to use `filter` specifically you would have to add an assertion.